# All rectangles in one iteration of a game loop drawing the same colour despite explicit colour arguments

Tags: python, sdl, pygame

I'm writing a simple toy in Pygame. When you press a key on the home row, it does a little burst of particles.

```
class Particle():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    size = 0
    colour = (255, 255, 255)
    rect = None
    def __init__(self, x, y, size, colour):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.colour = colour # Particle has its own colour 
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.size, self.size)

class Burst():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    colour = (255, 255, 255)
    count = 0
    sound = None
    particles = []

    def __init__(self, x, y, colour, count, sound):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.colour = colour # Burst has its own colour, too - all its particles should have the same colour as it
        self.count = count
        self.sound = sound
        self.particles.append(Particle(self.x, self.y, 5, self.colour))

    def update(self):
        self.particles.append(Particle(random.randint(1, 30) + self.x, random.randint(1, 30) + self.y, 5, self.colour))
    def draw(self):
        global screen
        for p in self.particles:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, p.colour, p.rect) # This draws the particles with the correct colours
            #pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, (60, 60, 120, 120), 4) # This draws the particles all the same colour
            #screen.fill(p.colour, p.rect) # This draws the particles all the same colour
```

The line you're looking for is in Burst.draw. For some reason, only the uncommented one works correctly. The other two lines, which should be the same as far as I can tell, only draw the first burst's particles correctly. Any subsequent bursts change all particles onscreen to match their colour.

I can provide more code, but there's not much more to it. Basically keypresses add Bursts to an array, and every tick I step through that array calling update() and draw().

Does anyone know what I did wrong, and then accidentally fixed?

Comment: Doesn't the line  
#pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, (60, 60, 120, 120), 4)
draw them as Burst.colour, instead of Particle.colour?

Comment: Yes, but these should have the same value. Particle.colour is initialised to be the same as the Burst.colour of the Burst that it is part of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because all particles in the screen belong to the same collection Burst.particles.
And every time you process a Burst you are processing **all** the particles, and all gets painted with the last colour.

Just move the initialization `particles = []` to the `init` method.

```
def __init__(self, x, y, colour, count, sound):
    ...
    self.particles = []
    self.particles.append(Particle(self.x, self.y, 5, self.colour))
```

**Update**

You are using a Java/C# style of coding classes. You shouldn't put any of the initializations at the class level, unless they are constants or class attributes.

IE:

```
class Burst():

    class_attribute = 0       # declaration of class (static) attribute

    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.attribute = 0    # declaration of object (regular) attribute
```

You shouldn't make class declarations of attribute you will use a object attributes.
Just remove all the declarations previous to the init method in both classes.

Comment: Ah! This is incredibly helpful. Thank you very much. Your answer is probably going to save me an awful lot of trouble later. I didn't know the way class attributes worked at all.